# Qt, exclude an Event from qApp->processEvents()

Tags: c++, events, qt, signal-processing, signals

I have a loop that performs heavy IO so I call qApp->processEvents() from time to time to keep the GUI reactive. On Linux this leads to a serious bug because an Event is called ahead of schedule.

Is there a possiblity to exclude the Event from qApp->processEvents()?

Comment: What kind of event? Did you try the flags described in http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qeventloop.html#ProcessEventsFlag-enum ? Did you consider using another thread?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you can exclude it from `processEvents` but by installing an [event filter](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qobject.html#eventFilter) you should be able to prevent the event from being handled.